# Battery drain in different distributions of linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, battery

Does fast battery drain happens in every distributions of Linux, or is this the case only with some distributions of linux like ubuntu.

Comment: There are quite a few Linux distributions and quite a few ways to configure them.

Comment: This is wayy too general. With my current laptop, I get fast drain on every distro I've tried. On my old one, it was only Ubuntu. On Dell laptops, battery life is usually very good, especially on Ubuntu. Same for HP. Macs have insane batteries, so it doesn't really matter for them. If you have a certain configuration you're talking about, then maybe this question can be answered. Otherwise, you might as well be asking if trees can think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there are specific optimizations applied distributions, battery drain should be fairly consistent across distros. However, different distros have different sets of applications running by default. Power hungry applications can kill your battery.